# Groovy: controlling a shell processes I/O prompts

Tags: shell, groovy, process, input

From groovy I need to run a shell command which I didn't write. This command prompts the user for various input values. So I'm trying to figure out how to respond to prompts from a groovy script. So far I have:

```
Process proc = command.execute()
parms.each() {value -> 
    proc << String.valueOf(value) + "\n"
}
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder()
proc.waitForProcessOutput(output, output)
return output.toString()
```

This works in that command is started and the parms are passed to it, except that all the parms are passed to the first prompt from command.

I'm new to groovy so I'm having trouble figuring out how to deal with this. Ideally I'd like to be able to pick up each prompt and give the matching reply, rather than this method which makes a fragile assumption about the order of prompts.

Has anyone done anything like this before with groovy?

Comment: Have you had any look here. I'm looking for the same

Answer (score 1):

you could try using [expectj](http://expectj.sourceforge.net/), which is a jvm implementation of '[expect](http://www.nist.gov/el/msid/expect.cfm)'.

(not groovy-specific, but worth a look)

HTH